# How to enable networking before User Data scripts are run in AWS Windows instances

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have been struggling with bootstrapping my Windows instances in AWS.  I need to download some things from S3 and other places when the instance starts up and execute them.

This seems to be really straightforward for Linux instances, but not so much for Windows instances.

I have a user data script that works when I run it after logging into the instance, but it doesn't work when it runs as part of the EC2Launch/EC2Config described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html

I've found that the reason it doesn't work is that I am unable to download things from the internet due to: "The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified service does not exist."

Really what I'm trying to do is the following:

1. Download AWS_CLI Installer

   - Right now I'm using bitsadmin to try to download the installer from https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi
2. Install AWS_CLI

   - I am able to install the CLI with the CLI installer using msiexec and the /qn flags once it's on the box
3. Pull items from S3

   - This should be able to be done with aws s3 cp or sync
4. Install Python  (installer stored in S3)

   - I am able to install the installer with msiexec once it's on the box similar to the CLI installer
5. Execute (python) scripts pulled from S3

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?  This all works after I RDP in, but not as part of the Launch Script.

**TL;DR** - I need to download things using the EC2Launch User Data script provided to my EC2 Windows instances but the network doesn't seem to be available when it runs.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you advise if the user and service referenced in the error message exist? I do this all the time time in windows there is never an issue. Just got to resolve the errors of course.

Comment: bits admin? What is that? Are you using PowerShell? You may want to post your script for review.

Answer (score 0):

I Ran into a similar issue, I was using BITS to download an installer on a "user data" script and was getting the same error: "The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not logged on to the network. The specified service does not exist."

**This not due to network issues**, but rather to how BITS works, the user starting the download job must be logged on the machine, which it seems not to be the case for "user data" execution, which ["runs as" the local Administrator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html#user-data-execution) without the user being logged in a way that BITS recognizes. From [BITS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/users-and-network-connections):

> For BITS to detect that a user is logged on, the user must use one of the following interactive logon options:
>
> - Log on through the Welcome screen.
> - Log on to a terminal client.
> - Use fast user switching.
> - Starting with Windows 10, version, log on from another device using Remote Powershell.

During the script execution the network is mounted and ready to use, you can download your files using other methods that do not rely on BITS(e.g.: [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) ([rather slow](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell) for bigger files) or using  [System.Net.WebClient](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=486574), both on PowerShell).